# How to Return true if String array having mix of Int and String type value converted to int in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, split

I have string which I split to see if any of the split value is string. If so I want to return true else false.

```
string words = "1 2 c 5";
```

Easy approach, I can follow by converting into int array and then compare value side by side.

```
int[] iar = words.Split(' ').Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out n) ? n : 0).ToArray();
```

Can any one recommend better approach?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I got your question straight: you want to return true if a given string has numbers into it?

Comment: Your approach doesn't even return a boolean like you say you want to return. and what is the definition to you of a "better" approach?

Comment: I think it's that the return value should be `true` if one of the values is *not* a number.  That doesn't explain why the existing approach returns an array of `int` though...

Comment: `(new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 }).Any(x => words.Contains(x.ToString()));` Is that really it?

Comment: @AndreCalil that's the same as my answer except you are reimplementing the regular expression functionality yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply check without using `Split`:

```
var result = words.Any(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) 
                         && !char.IsDigit(c));
```

Or using `Split`:

```
var result = words.Split()
                  .Any(w => w.Any(c => !char.IsDigit(c)));
```

The point is you can use `char.IsDigit` to check instead of using `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`.

Comment: Would that flag the " " spaces as non-digits?

Comment: I'd use `char.IsWhiteSpace` instead of `' '` personally.

Comment: This is helpful - var result = words.Any(!char.IsDigit(c));

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a simple little method:

```
public static bool CheckForNum(string[] wordsArr)
{
     int i = 0;
     foreach (string s in wordsArr)
     {
         if (Int32.TryParse(s, out i))
         {
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Using:

```
bool result = CheckForNum(words.Split(' '));
Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: it's not a bad answer. There are some abusive downvoters hovering on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regular expression? If a string has words and numbers in it, it must have letters and number characters. I don't entirely understand the logic in your question, so you may need to adjust the logic here.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string words = "1 2 c 5";

Match numberMatch = Regex.Match(words, @"[0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match letterMatch = Regex.Match(words, @"[a-zA-Z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (numberMatch.Success && letterMatch.Success)
{
    // there are letters and numbers
}
```

Comment: A regex in this situation looks a bit overkill, doesn't it?

Comment: No I don't think so. It's very simple. No more or less complicated than splitting a string. Did you downvote this answer @AndreCalil? Can you say why?

Comment: No, I didn't. If I had I would justify it. Regex is very powerful, but it's expensive too. In this situation, it's an overkill. Also, `Contains` does not use a regex, it's an ordinal search. In fact, your answer *works*, so I'm upvoting it. However, it's not the best solution.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't that inefficient in .NET. If it were compiled first then I honestly don't see the problem. Thanks for the upvote, I was slightly affronted that my answer got an immediate 2 downvotes and I wrongly assumed one was you. I apologise for that!

Comment: As for Contains, the complexity of the solution you gave in your comment is at least O(N). I can't speak for the complexity of the regular expression, but I assume there would be optimisations as this is precisely what regexes are designed for.

Comment: It's ok, I know this feeling. I'm not saying that regex are inefficient at all, I'm just stating that they are less efficient than a simple `string.Contains`. You can measure that =)

Comment: Just out of curiosity I did compare them (using Mono). For 1,000,000 reps, a compiled regular expression takes 3.9 seconds, your version takes 1.5 seconds so there's a factor of 2.6 over a million runs. You are correct, yours is more efficient. (I would still argue that it's a premature optimisation and that using a regex is clearer!)

Comment: thanks very much for taking the time for that! I would upvote again if I could =)